# R base plot does not display xticks and yticks

Tags: r, plot

I tried plotting  a vector converted into a timeseries data.
Used R base's plot

```
plot(data_1,ylab='Customer Footfall',xlab='Weeks')
```

But the plot appears without the xticks and yticks.

Sample data:
[image]

Comment: Please make your post reproducible by including minimal & representative sample data. It's hard to help since we don't know anything about `data_1`.

Comment: The examples for the `ts` function include a simple plot, `plot(nhtemp)`, using a data set included with R. It has tick marks (`help(ts)`).